# Render page multiple times while looping over a queryset in the view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have this view, where essentially I want to keep rendering the page with the next question in the list until I finish all the questions in 'questions'. My problem is keeping track of where in the list 'questions' I am. Currently I was thinking using a hidden field in my form to keep track of it, like I am with the test ID, but that doesn't make sense as it would send the entire list and not just what questions are left...

```
def test_detail(request, pk=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        test_id = request.POST['test']
        test = get_object_or_404(Test, pk=test_id)
        question = Question.objects.get(question__exact=request.POST['question'])
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST, question=question)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #Render page again continuously until no more questions left
    else:
        test = Test.objects.get(pk=pk)
        questions = Question.objects.filter(test_id=pk).order_by('?')
        for question in questions:
            form = ResponseForm(question=question)
            return render(request, 'site/test.html', {'test': test, 'questions': questions, 'question': question, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Looping won't work because you can send only one `response` object per `request` object.

Comment: @xyres I'm aware of that, but what I want to do is send a difference response form for each question in the queryset

Comment: multiple ajax requests may do the trick ... JMHO

Comment: To correct my previous comment: Looping won't work because the function returns on the first iteration of the loop, and therefore the loop will stop too.

Comment: @user2151557 You mean multiple forms on a single response? If so, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep current question id in session or pass through view parameter or anywhere you want but in general it seems that you need something like [django-formtools](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/) which is used exactly for multi-step forms. It was previously in django.contrib and called "Form Wizard".

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer on a hunch that you need to send many forms (one for each question) in a single response. You can do it like this:

```
def test_detail(request, pk=None):
    # your other logic ...
    # ...
    questions = Question.objects.filter(test_id=pk).order_by('?')

    # Create an empty list which will contain all the forms
    forms = []

    # Now append ResponseForm objects to `forms` list using a loop
    for question in questions:
        forms.append(ResponseForm(question=question))

    return render(request, 'site/test.html', {'forms': forms, 'test': test, 
                  'questions': questions})
```

Now, in your templates, just use a for loop:

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
```